# jQuery: exclude some elements by classes and select the rest

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I use the following code to select all external links on the page

```
items = jQuery("a[href^=\'http:\']").not("[href*=\'" + window.location.host + "\']");
```

But I need to exclude links from tags with some known classes, e.g. I want to exclude "class1" and "class4" and select whatever have left.

```
<body>
<div>
  <p class="class1">
    <span class="class2"><a href="#">link</a></span>
    <span class="class2"><a href="#">link</a></span>
  </p>
</div>
<p class="class3"><a href="#">link</a></p>
<div class="class4"><a href="#">link</a></div>
<a href="#">link</a>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are already using `not()`, what else do you need to know?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I don't know to use not() to exclude classes.

Answer (score 1):

Html elements can have multiple classes by seperating each class name with a space.  Is it not possible to just add an additional class name to the elements you want to select, and not add it to the ones you don't want to select?

Comment: Seems like a perfectly valid and logical solution to me.

Comment: There would be no problems if the target elements were marked. The script should skip links from e.g. <div class="navigation"> tag.